# NGXS test for Angular-Test-Mode is broken in Angular 13

Tags: ngxs

We are working on an Angular application that uses among other things Ngxs (version 3.7.3). Currently we are using Angular 12.2 and want to upgrade to Angular 13. We have successfully upgraded the application to Angular 13, unfortunately a significant number of our unit tests are failing, all with the same exception generated by the routing module. We found the ngxs-router-plugin in the stack traces and tries to find out what was going on. NGXS checks if Angular is in test-mode - the function `isAngularInTestMode` in module `/internals/src/angular.ts` - and configures itself accordingly. This check is broken.

We have seen that ngxs has fixed the problem - the fix can be found on the master branch. We don't when the next release is due. Does anybody know when the next ngxs release is due? Is anybody else  experiencing the same problem, and if so do you have a workaround?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After having the exact same issue and further checking the NGXS docs, I found that dev-builds are available from the `master` branch - the thing that initially threw me off was that they are labeled with the same version prefix as the last `stable` (tag `latest`) build.

So in short: the workaround is to use the `dev` tag, or the dev-version that effectively fixed the issue - in this case `3.7.3-dev.master-33cace6`